# Push Team City Release to Octopus Deploy

Tags: teamcity, octopus-deploy

I am having problems trying to push a .zip artifact from Team City to Octopus Deploy and would like to requisition some help with this.

Using the "OctopusDeploy: Push packages" runner on Team City, I am trying to push the artifact "Release.%MajorVersion%.%MinorVersion%.%build.number%.zip" to our Octopus Server.

This, however, fails with the following error message:

```
[04:58:19][Octopus Deploy] Please specify a package to push
[04:58:19][Octopus Deploy] Exit code: -1
[04:58:19][Octopus Deploy] Octo.exe exit code: -1
[04:58:19][Step 3/3] Unable to create or deploy release. Please check the build log for details on the error.
```

In the "Artifacts path" field of the "General Settings" section of the Build Configuration in Team City, I have defined the following artifact to be created:

```
+:Release => Release.%MajorVersion%.%MinorVersion%.%build.number%.zip
-:Release/**/*.xml => Release.%MajorVersion%.%MinorVersion%.%build.number%.zip
```

This creates the file "Release.%MajorVersion%.%MinorVersion%.%build.number%.zip" in the path [Team City Data Directory]\system\artifacts[Project Name][Configuration Name][Unique Build Number].

Next, I try to push this package to our Octopus Server by using the "OctopusDeploy: Push packages" runner with the "Package paths" parameter set to "Release.%MajorVersion%.%MinorVersion%.%build.number%.zip", since the descriptive text says "These follow the same rules as TeamCity artifact paths."

However, this does not appear to work.

I would like to know why, and how I could get it to work.

My main problem at this point is that I don't know how I can address the "Release.%MajorVersion%.%MinorVersion%.%build.number%.zip" file in the mutable artifacts directory.

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer**

You need to be more specific with the package path in the `OctopusDeploy: Push packages` step. By simply passing `Release.%MajorVersion%.%MinorVersion%.%build.number%.zip` you are telling that step to get the package with that name at the root of your `workdir`. But as you already said, that package is actually sitting on `[Team City Data Directory]\system\artifacts[Project Name][Configuration Name][Unique Build Number]`

So try passing the full path of the `zip` file like

`[Team City Data Directory]\system\artifacts[Project Name][Configuration Name][Unique Build Number]\Release.%MajorVersion%.%MinorVersion%.%build.number%.zip`

*replace the values in square brackets with the apropriate TeamCity variable*

**Long Answer**

When it says *These follow the same rules as TeamCity artifact paths* it means that you can use the same kind of expressions like `+:Release => Release.zip` to create artifacts. It doesn't mean that It'll look for files into the artifacts' directory.

The `OctopusDeploy: Push packages` not only allows you to `push` packages, but also `pack` them (not that obvious, yeah). So if you put (same) below expression in that field, It'll create the package and push it to the repository

`+:Release => Release.%MajorVersion%.%MinorVersion%.%build.number%.zip
-:Release/**/*.xml => Release.%MajorVersion%.%MinorVersion%.%build.number%.zip`

Additionally if you check the box `Publish packages as build artifacts` the `zip` file will also be available as a TeamCity artifact. So you wouldn't technically need need the current step where you are creating the artifact (unless it has another purpose in your build process of course)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add `OctoPack` to you project from NuGet Package Manager.